# Color background using array and object , for a reversable repeatable div

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
var ar = ["one_in", "two_in", "three_in"];
    var colors = {};
    [ar[0]] = 'blue';
    [ar[1]] = 'green';
    [ar[2]] = 'red';
x = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
for (var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++ ){
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[x[i].className];
}
```

```css
.one_in,.two_in{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="one_in"></div><div class="two_in"></div>
```

why not this working again , i want to make the div colored with their respective colors and `div` `class` as mentioned in the array and object, i know its a simple question for you , may be a small mistake

https://jsfiddle.net/qothk6g3/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `color` in front of the property with an item of the array as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```js
var ar = ["one_in", "two_in", "three_in"],
    x = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV'),
    i,
    colors = {};

colors[ar[0]] = 'blue';
colors[ar[1]] = 'green';
colors[ar[2]] = 'red';

for (i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[x[i].className];
}
```

```css
.one_in,.two_in { width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<div class="one_in"></div><div class="two_in"></div>
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it

Comment: div's are reversable and repeatable

Comment: your div `<div class="three_in"></div>` has no height, actually, because of no css class, and no content. ich it has some content, you could see the background color.

Comment: in the last case, you could use for a repeated color use the remainder operator, like `x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i % colors.length];`. the last box starts with blue again. and if more boxes to come, you get repeated the other colors as well.

Comment: i mean where ever i place the div it should get the color anywhere left right top reverse repeat , i dont want to repeat indeed

Comment: i don't get you. do you mind to add an example? (btw, this is far away from your original post.)

Comment: check here https://jsfiddle.net/qothk6g3/5/ , last one goes blank , `one_in` should be blue , `two_in` should be green ...and  respectively

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131449/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-anjali).